# Onclick of action buttons like edit delete how to highlight the related row in angular

Tags: angular

Onclick of action buttons like edit ,delete how to highlight the related particular row in the below table using  angular4

[image]

```
 <div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableHead" *ngFor="let tableKey of ResultData1">
      <strong>{{ tableKey}}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rTableRow" *ngFor="let data of dataFromServer ; let i = index;" (click)="setClickedRow(i)" >
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.id}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.firstName}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.email}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.phoneNum}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.order}}</div>

    <div class="rTableCell">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">
        Add
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" (click)="dataIndex(i)">
        Edit
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" (click)="deleteData(i)">
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which library you're using to display grid?

Comment: which module means,i did'nt get your question

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question and add your latest code for further understanding.

Comment: can you update with the HTML code

Comment: really! you need to read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you have found the correct answer mark the solution correct because other people with think this question is still open.

Comment: this solution not working for me still

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth if i give value for  (this.selectedId = 2) It is not working

Comment: @supriya whats the error

Comment: @ AbhishekEkaanth yeah  its working just i did small change thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to make use of `ngClass`

```
<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableHead" *ngFor="let tableKey of ResultData1">
      <strong>{{ tableKey}}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rTableRow" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':data.id === selectedId ? 'green' : 'white' }" *ngFor="let data of dataFromServer ; let i = index;" >
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.id}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.firstName}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.email}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.phoneNum}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell">{{data.order}}</div>

    <div class="rTableCell">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal  (click)="AddIndex(data)">
        Add
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" (click)="dataIndex(data)">
        Edit
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" (click)="deleteData(data)">
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in your TS you can call those methods and then assign the clicked value like

```
dataIndex(data){
this.selectedId = data.id;
}
```

you can do this in all the methods